# Change cursor icon on key press

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the cursor icon on a key press?  I have an app that moves and splits panels. When you are on the border of a panel you can split it or move it. When you press ctrl to split it I would like the cursor icon to change.

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const BlenderSplitter = ( {children, layout} ) => {

    // useState for the layout.  This represents how sub-panes are divided and
    // whatnot
    const [layoutState, setLayoutState] = useState(layout);

    // Used to lookup child by name
    const childMap = {};
    children.forEach( e => childMap[ e.props.id ] = e );

    // Each state has a StateEnum called "stateEnum" along with whatever
    // data is needed for that state.  The following are the possible values
    // for the enum.
    const StateEnum = {
        None: "None",
        ElgibleToMove: "ElgibleToMove", // The cursor is over a split which is eligible to move
        AboutToMove: "AboutToMove",     // User pressed mouse button and is about to drag
        Moving: "Moving",               // User is dragging with mouse pressed
        ElgibleToCopy: "ElgibleToCopy", // Cursor is over a split and ctrl is pressed
        AboutToCopy: "AboutToCopy",     // User has pressed mouse button with ctrl and is about to drag
    }

    // useState for storing state information
    const [state, setState] = useState( { //Initial state set to "none"
        stateEnum: StateEnum.None,
    } );

    // Function for converting from pixels to percent (within this container).
    // Everything within this component is in a percent coordinate system
    const eventToPercentVector = e => {
        const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            x: (e.clientX-rect.left)/(rect.right-rect.left) * 100,
            y: (e.clientY-rect.top)/(rect.bottom-rect.top) * 100 };
    }

    // The margin that is close enough to a split to be considered "on" the split.
    // This is within percent (not pixels).
    const reshapeMargin = 1;

    // Function that finds the nearest split(s) to a given vector (mouse pointer location).  This 
    // method returns an array of arrays.  The outer array is the number of "matches" and each sub-array
    // represents a "match".  So for example, if the pointer is not near any split, then this will return
    // an empty array.  If it matches 3 splits (like the pointer is near a T-junction), then the outer array
    // will contain 3 sub-arrays.  Each sub-array represents a matching split.  So for example, the
    // following example layout code:
    //
    // const layout = {
    //   areTopLevelSplittersVertical: false,

    //   content: [
    //     "one",
    //     20,
    //     [ "two", 40, "three" ],
    //     70,
    //     "four"
    //   ]
    // };
    //
    // Would produce this layout of components (the 40, 20, and 70 represent what percent the splits are.
    // They would not be displayed):
    //
    //        40
    //     ┌─────────┐
    //     │   one   │
    //     │         │
    //   20├───┬─────┤
    //     │   │     │
    //     │two│three│
    //     │   │     │
    //   70├───┴─────┤
    //     │  four   │
    //     │         │
    //     └─────────┘
    //
    // The array identifier for the horizontal 20% split would be [1].  As it is element 1 of the content array.
    // The 70% split would be [3].  Since the vertical 40% split is nested within element 2, it's identifier
    // would be [2,1].  Though the outer edges are not specified in the array, they are still identified by this
    // function.  So for example, the horizontal line above "one" would be [-1].  The horizontal line below
    // "four" would be [5], the short vertical line to the left of two would be [2,-1], and the short vertical
    // line to the right of three would be [2,3].
    //
    // The "shallow" parameter tells this function how "deep" to look.  The meat of this function is recursive.
    // If shallow was true, then this method would return a split as soon as it finds one.  It would not
    // recursively call itself on the bordering subcomponents.  If shallow were true, it would.  So for example,
    // imagine the mouse were on the split right above the "r" in "four".  If shallow were true, then this
    // function would return [[3]] (a single match of split [3]).  This is invoked when moving splits as one
    // would only needs to move split [3].  If shallow were false, then it would return: [[2,2,1],[3]].  This
    // is invoked when copying splits.  If the user were to select that point and copy up, it would copy split
    // [2,2,1].  If they were to copy down, it would copy split [3].
    const findNearestSplit = (percentVector,shallow) => {
        return findNearestSplitRecursive(percentVector,layoutState.content,{x:reshapeMargin,y:reshapeMargin},layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical,shallow);
    }

    // This is the recursive method that does the work for the method above.
    const findNearestSplitRecursive = (percentVector,content,margin,isCurrentSplitterVertical,shallow) => {
        var valToTest;
        var marginToTest;
        if( isCurrentSplitterVertical ) {
            valToTest = percentVector.x;
            marginToTest = margin.x;
        } else {
            valToTest = percentVector.y;
            marginToTest = margin.y;
        }

        const isArray = Array.isArray(content);
        const length = isArray ? content.length : null;

        var foundIndex;
        var childCandidateIndices;
        if( testWithinMargin( valToTest, 0, marginToTest ) ) { // is at min edge
            foundIndex = -1;
            childCandidateIndices = isArray ? [ 0 ] : null;
        } else if( testWithinMargin( valToTest, 100, marginToTest ) ) { // is at max edge
            if( isArray ) {
                foundIndex = length;
                childCandidateIndices = [ length-1 ];
            } else {
                foundIndex = 1;
                childCandidateIndices = null;
            }
        } else { // is somewhere between
            if( isArray ) {
                const searchResult = binarySearch(content,valToTest,marginToTest);
                if( searchResult%2==0 ) {
                    // If it was a component and not a split
                    foundIndex = null;
                    childCandidateIndices = [ searchResult ];
                } else {
                    // If it was a split
                    foundIndex = searchResult;
                    childCandidateIndices = [ foundIndex-1, foundIndex+1 ];
                }
            } else {
                foundIndex = null;
                childCandidateIndices = null;
            }
        }

        var returnMe = [];
        if( shallow && foundIndex!=null ) {
            returnMe.push([foundIndex]);
        } else {
            if( isArray ) {
                childCandidateIndices.forEach( childIndex => {
                    const minValue = childIndex===0 ? 0 : content[childIndex-1];
                    const maxValue = childIndex===length-1 ? length-1 : content[childIndex+1];

                    var subPercentVector = convertVector(minValue,maxValue,isCurrentSplitterVertical,percentVector);
                    var subMargin = convertMargin(minValue,maxValue,isCurrentSplitterVertical,margin);

                    var recurseArray = findNearestSplitRecursive(subPercentVector,content[childIndex],subMargin,!isCurrentSplitterVertical,shallow);
                    if( recurseArray.length>0 ) {
                        recurseArray.forEach( subArray => {
                            var myArray = [childIndex];
                            myArray = myArray.concat(subArray);
                            returnMe.push(myArray);
                        });
                    } else {
                        if( foundIndex!==null ) {
                            returnMe.push([foundIndex]);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if( foundIndex!==null ) {
                    returnMe.push([foundIndex]);
                }
            }
        }

        return returnMe;
    }

    // Simply tests is a value is within a given margin
    const testWithinMargin = (one, two, margin) => Math.abs(one - two) <= margin;

    // Performs a binary search within a context array.  For a point to be only
    // a split, it must be within the reshapeMargin (either wide).  Otherwise,
    // this function returns the index of the component that the point resides
    // within. This function is not recursive nor knows anything about nested
    // arrays.  It only knows about whatever array it is passed.  This call would
    // be invoked again on a sub-array if necessary.  It is not passed a point
    // (x,y), but just a single value (x or y).
    const binarySearch = (content,testForMe,margin) => {

        var minIndex = -1;
        var maxIndex = content.length;
        var foundIndex = null;
        var currentIndex;

        while(minIndex+2<maxIndex) {
            currentIndex = (minIndex+maxIndex)/2;
            if( currentIndex%2===0 ) {
                currentIndex--;
            }
            const currentValue = content[currentIndex];
            if( testWithinMargin( currentValue, testForMe, margin ) ) {
                foundIndex = currentIndex;
                break;
            } else if( testForMe > currentValue ) {
                minIndex = currentIndex;
            } else {
                maxIndex = currentIndex;
            }
        }

        if (foundIndex===null) {
            foundIndex = minIndex+1;
        }

        return foundIndex;
    }

    // At the top container level, 0% is the top/left corner and 100%
    // is on the bottom/right corner.  When recursively calculating for
    // nested components, the vector is converted to a percentage
    // coordinate that corresponds to child components.  For example,
    // in the layout below:
    //     ┌─────────┐
    //     │   one   │
    //     ├───┬─────┤
    //     │   │+    │
    //     │two│three│
    //     │   │     │
    //     └───┴─────┘
    // The point marked by "+" may about (50%,50%) in relation to
    // the outer most container, but only at (10%,20%) in relation to
    // child component "three".
    const convertVector = (minValue,maxValue,isVertical,vector) => {
        const convFunction = val => 100*(val-minValue)/(maxValue-minValue);
        var subVector;
        if( isVertical ) {
            subVector = {
                x: convFunction(vector.x),
                y: vector.y
            };
        } else {
            subVector = {
                x: vector.x,
                y: convFunction(vector.y)
            };
        }
        return subVector;
    }

    // Similarly, margins change for child components too.  If 1% corresponds
    // to 10 pixels overall. Yet 10 pixels may be 1.3% for component three below.
    //     ┌─────────┐
    //     │   one   │
    //     ├───┬─────┤
    //     │   │     │
    //     │two│three│
    //     │   │     │
    //     └───┴─────┘
    // We don't want the margins getting smaller as people hover over nested
    // components and splits.
    const convertMargin = (minValue,maxValue,isVertical,margin) => {
        const marginFunction = val => val*100/(maxValue-minValue);
        var subMargin;
        if( isVertical ) {
            subMargin = {
                x: marginFunction(margin.x),
                y: margin.y
            };
        } else {
            subMargin = {
                x: margin.x,
                y: marginFunction(margin.y)
            };
        }
        return subMargin;
    }

    // Just for debug printing.
    const arrayToStringRecursive = (a,str) => {
        if( Array.isArray(a) ) {
            str = str.concat("[");
            var first = true;
            a.forEach( e => {
                if( first ) {
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    str = str.concat(",");
                }
                str = arrayToStringRecursive(e,str);
            });
            str = str.concat("]");
        } else {
            str = str.concat(a);
        }
        //console.log("about to return str="+str);
        return str;
    }

    // Just for debug printing.
    const arrayToString = (a) => {
        return arrayToStringRecursive(a,"");
    }

    // Just for debug printing.
    const printArray = (label,a) => {
        console.log(`${label}=${arrayToString(a)}`);
    }

    // Just for debug printing.
    const pointToString = (p) => `(${p.x},${p.y})`;

    // Convenience function for determining if state is one of the copy states.
    const isCopyState = stateEnum =>
        stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy
        || stateEnum===StateEnum.AboutToCopy

    // Convenience function for setting state to None
    const setToNoneState = () => {
        setState( {
            stateEnum: StateEnum.None
        } );
    }

    // Convenience function for setting state to EligibleToMove.
    const setToElgibleToMoveState = (split) => {
        setState( {
            stateEnum: StateEnum.ElgibleToMove,
            split: split
        } );
    }

    // Convenience function for setting state to AboutToMove
    const setToAboutToMoveState = (split,pressSplitLocation,pressMouseLocation) => {
        setState( {
            stateEnum: StateEnum.AboutToMove,
            split: split,
            pressSplitLocation: pressSplitLocation,
            pressMouseLocation: pressMouseLocation
        } );
    }

    // Convenience function for setting state to Moving
    const setToMovingState = (split,pressSplitLocation,pressMouseLocation,currentMouseLocation) => {
        setState( {
            stateEnum: StateEnum.Moving,
            split: split,
            pressSplitLocation: pressSplitLocation,
            pressMouseLocation: pressMouseLocation,
            currentMouseLocation: currentMouseLocation
        } );
    }

    // Convenience function for setting state to EligibleToCopy
    const setToElgibleToCopyState = (split) => {
    
        setState( {
            stateEnum: StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy,
            split: split
        } );
    }

    // Convenience function for setting state to AboutToCopy
    const setToAboutToCopyState = (splits,pressLocation) => {
        setState( {
            stateEnum: StateEnum.AboutToCopy,
            splits: splits,
            pressLocation: pressLocation
        } );
    }

    // Function that evaluates the state of the mouse cursor, ctrl button, and mouse
    // button to determine what state this should be in.
    const determineState = (e) => {
        const stateEnum = state.stateEnum;
        const percent = eventToPercentVector(e);
        const nearSplit = findNearestSplit(percent,!isCopyState(stateEnum));
        const length = nearSplit.length;

        const isPressedNow = e.buttons &= 1;
        if( isPressedNow ) {
            if( stateEnum===StateEnum.None 
                    || stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy
                    || stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToMove ) {
                if(e.ctrlKey) {
                    if( length>0 && length<3 ) {
                        const nearSplits = findNearestSplit(percent,false);
                        setToAboutToCopyState(nearSplits,percent);

                    }
                } else {
                    if( length>0 ) {
                        setToAboutToMoveState(nearSplit,getSplitLocation(nearSplit[0]),percent);
                    }
                }
            } else if( stateEnum===StateEnum.AboutToCopy ) {
                const nearSplits = findNearestSplit(percent,false);
                if( JSON.stringify(nearSplits) !== JSON.stringify(state.splits) ) {
                    const isVertical = state.splits[0].length%2 === 1 ? layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical : !layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical;
                    var chosenIndex;
                    var loc;
                    if( isVertical ) {
                        chosenIndex = percent.x < state.pressLocation.x ? 0 : 1;
                        loc = percent.x;
                    } else {
                        chosenIndex = percent.y < state.pressLocation.y ? 0 : 1;
                        loc = percent.y;
                    }
                    var chosenSplit;
                    if(state.splits.length===1) {
                        // Left most split will only have 1 element but we want to treat it as the right/bottom most.
                        chosenSplit = state.splits[0];
                    } else {
                        chosenSplit = state.splits[chosenIndex];
                    }
                    insertSplit( chosenSplit, loc, chosenIndex===1 );
                    if(chosenIndex===1) {
                        chosenSplit[ chosenSplit.length-1 ]+=2;
                    }
                    setToMovingState(chosenSplit,loc,percent,percent);
          document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //disable text select
                }

            } else if( stateEnum===StateEnum.AboutToMove ) {
                if( JSON.stringify(nearSplit) !== JSON.stringify(state.nearSplit) ) {
                    setToMovingState(state.split[0],state.pressSplitLocation,state.pressMouseLocation,percent);
          document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //disable text select
                }
            } else if( stateEnum===StateEnum.Moving ) {
                setToMovingState(state.split,state.pressSplitLocation,state.pressMouseLocation,percent);
        document.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); //disable text select
            }
        } else if(e.ctrlKey) {
            if( length>0 && length<3 ) {
                setToElgibleToCopyState(nearSplit);
            } else {
                setToNoneState();
            }
        } else if( length===0 ) {
            setToNoneState();
        } else {
            setToElgibleToMoveState(nearSplit);
        }
    }

    // Draws cursor based on current state
    const updateCursor = e => {
        const target = e.currentTarget;
    var cursorToUse;
    


        if( state.stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToMove ) {
            var isVertical;

            if( layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical ) {
                isVertical = true;
            } else {
                isVertical = false;
            }

            if( state.split[0].length%2 === 0 ) {
                isVertical = !isVertical;
            }

            if( isVertical ) {
                cursorToUse = "col-resize";
            } else {
                cursorToUse = "row-resize";
            }
      
        } else if( state.stateEnum===StateEnum.ElgibleToCopy ) {
     cursorToUse = "copy";
        } else {
            cursorToUse = "default";
        }
        target.style.cursor = cursorToUse;
    }

    // Generic function for deep copying the content array.  Used when
    // changing the content.
    const deepContentCopy = (content) => {
        if(Array.isArray(content)) {
            var ret=[];
            content.forEach( element => { ret.push( deepContentCopy(element) ); } );
            return ret;
        } else {
            return content;
        }
    }

    // Method for getting split location percentage.  The split parameter is
    // an array identifier (like [1,2,3]) and it's location percentage is returned.
    const getSplitLocation = split => {
        var current = layoutState.content;
        split.forEach( element => {
            current = current[element];
        } );
        return current;
    }

    // Method for setting split location percentage.  The split parameter is
    // an array identifier (like [1,2,3]) and the loc is a percentage (0-100)
    const setSplitLocation = (split,loc) => {
        var copy = deepContentCopy(layoutState.content);
        var copyLayoutState = {
            areTopLevelSplittersVertical: layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical,
            content: copy
        };

        var parent = copy;
        for( var i=0;i<split.length-1;i++) {
            parent = parent[ split[i] ];
        }
        const last = split[ split.length-1 ];
        parent[ last ] = loc
        setLayoutState(copyLayoutState);
    }

    // This returns the location of splits on either side of a given
    // index.  This is best shown with an example:
    //
    // percentage: 0%   25%   50%   75%   100%
    //             ┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
    //             │ one │ two │three│four │
    //             └─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
    //     index: -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
    //
    // The min/max of distance 1 from index 2 would be 25% and 50%.
    // The min/max of distance 2 from index 3 would be 25% and 75%.
    //
    // It basically returns the value of the splits on each side of
    // from a given index, but is smart in that it returns 0% and
    // 100% rather than try to access an array out of bounds.
    const calcMinMax = (parent,index,distance) => {
        var minValue;
        var maxValue;

        if( index-distance<0 ) {
            minValue = 0;
        } else {
            minValue = parent[ index - distance ];
        }

        if( index+distance>=parent.length) {
            maxValue = 100;
        } else {
            maxValue = parent[ index + distance ];
        }

        return {
            minValue: minValue,
            maxValue: maxValue
        }
    }

    // Performs the move state action.
    const moveSplit = (movingState) => {
        var isVertical = layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical;
        var currentMouseLocation = movingState.currentMouseLocation;

        // This gets the parent of the split in question.
        const split = movingState.split;
        var parent = layoutState.content;
        for( var i=0;i<split.length-1;i++) {
            const component = split[i];

            const {minValue,maxValue} = calcMinMax(parent,component,1);

            currentMouseLocation = convertVector(minValue,maxValue,isVertical,currentMouseLocation);
            isVertical = !isVertical;
            parent = parent[ component ];
        }

        var loc = isVertical ? currentMouseLocation.x : currentMouseLocation.y;

        const splitIndex = split.length-1;
        const {minValue,maxValue} = calcMinMax(parent,split[splitIndex],2);
        if( loc+reshapeMargin>=maxValue ) {
            // The user moved the split beyond the edge of the next spit.  Delete it (and the component it contained).
            parent.splice( split[splitIndex], 2 );
            setToNoneState();
        } else if ( loc-reshapeMargin<=minValue ) {
            // The user moved the split beyond the edge of the previous spit.  Delete it (and the component it contained).
            parent.splice( split[splitIndex]-1, 2 );
            setToNoneState();
        } else {
            // Set new split location.
            setSplitLocation(split,loc);
        }
    }

    // Inserts a split before or after the provided split at given location.
    const insertSplit = (split, loc, isAfter) => {
        var copy = deepContentCopy(layoutState.content);
        if( !Array.isArray(copy) ) {
            copy = [copy];
        }
        var copyLayoutState = {
            areTopLevelSplittersVertical: layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical,
            content: copy
        };

        var parent = copy;
        for( var i=0;i<split.length-1;i++) {
            var child = parent[ split[i] ];
            if( !Array.isArray(child) ) {
                child = [child];
                parent[ split[i] ] = child;
            }
            parent = child;
        }
        const last = split[ split.length-1 ];
        if(isAfter) {
            parent.splice( last+1, 0, loc );
            parent.splice( last+1, 0, "chooser" );
        } else {
            parent.splice( last, 0, "chooser" );
            parent.splice( last, 0, loc );
        }
        setLayoutState(copyLayoutState);
    }

    // Handler for the mouse move event
    const mouseMoved = (e) => {
        determineState(e);
        updateCursor(e);

        if( state.stateEnum===StateEnum.Moving ) {
            moveSplit(state);
        }
    }

    // Handler for the mouse down event
    const mouseDown = (e) => {
        determineState(e);
        updateCursor(e);
    }

    // Handler for the mouse up event
    const mouseUp = (e) => {
        determineState(e);
        updateCursor(e);
    }

    // Generates DOM for browser to display.
    const generateDOM = layoutState => {
        return (
        <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                tabIndex={0}
                onMouseMove={mouseMoved}
                onMouseDown={mouseDown}
                onMouseUp={mouseUp}>
            {generateContent(layoutState.content,layoutState.areTopLevelSplittersVertical)}
        </div>);
    }

    // Recursive function called by generateDOM.
    const generateContent = (layoutState,isCurrentSplitterVertical) => {

        var styleGenerator;
        if( isCurrentSplitterVertical ) {
            styleGenerator = percent => { return { height: "100%", width: percent+"%", overflow: "auto" } };
        } else {
            styleGenerator = percent => { return { height: percent+"%", width: "100%", overflow: "auto" } };
        }

        var content;
        if( Array.isArray(layoutState) ) {
            if( layoutState.length>0 ) {
                var lastPercent=0;
                var elements=[{
                    child: generateContent(layoutState[0],!isCurrentSplitterVertical)
                }];
                for(var i=1;i<layoutState.length;i++) {
                    var element = layoutState[i];
                    const elementPercent = element-lastPercent;
                    elements[elements.length-1].percent = elementPercent;
                    lastPercent += elementPercent;
                    i++;
                    if(i>=layoutState.length) {
                        throw "Expect content array to have odd number of elements.  Children name strings with splitter percentages between i="+i+" length="+layoutState.length+".";
                    }
                    elements.push( {
                        child: generateContent(layoutState[i],!isCurrentSplitterVertical)
                    });
                }

                elements[elements.length-1].percent = 100-lastPercent;

                content =
                    <div style={{display:"flex",
                            flexDirection:isCurrentSplitterVertical ? "row" : "column",
                            width: "100%",
                            height: "100%",
                    }}>
                        {elements.map( (element,index) => (
                        <div key={index} style={styleGenerator(element.percent)}>
                            {element.child}
                        </div> ))}
                    </div>
            } else {
                content = <p>no child!</p>;
            }
        } else {
            content = childMap[layoutState];
        }

        return content;
    }

    return generateDOM(layoutState);
}

export default BlenderSplitter;
```

```css
.App-logo {
    height: 40vmin;
    pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
    .App-logo {
        animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
    }
}

.App-header {
    /*min-height: 100vh;*/
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
    width: 600px;
    height: 500px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.App-link {
    color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.blah {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.App {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.ctrl-button {
  background: white;
  color: #333;
  border: none;
  cursor: copy;
}

.ass {
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 20px;
}

#chooser {
  background-color: #535353;

}

#one {
    background-color: rgb(255, 143, 143);
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#two {
    background-color: rgb(153, 255, 160);
}

#three {
    background-color: rgb(158, 158, 255);
}

#four {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 142);
}
```

I've been able to capture the key press but I'm don't know how to change the icon when that happens.

```js
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.ctrlKey) {
       document.body.style.cursor = "copy";
    }
};
```

**I made a sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/embed/jolly-swartz-f9ho3j?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Your code is exactly doing what you are trying. I've reduced the code to only your function and body tag. https://jsfiddle.net/64y7Lab3/ -- Note, you have to click into the window where the preview is

Comment: So since it's not working, something else is preventing it. Most probably because another Element is obove the body which has another cursor type. So maybe reduce your example to a minimal version where your Problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @Hoargarth Is there a way to make the cursor change when its next to a border?